# Django auto increment value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using Django models and I would like to get current value of auto increment field "id". 
I use this in my model class but still getting erros when I access with "userLog.id"

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

SO, how can I know id value of my object ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. It is not a very good way but it solves my problem. What I do is to make query in order to get primary_key value. Here is my python view code:

```
resu = request.session.get('userNow')
resuLog = json.loads(resu)
dataUserLog = resuLog[0]['fields']

sonNom = dataUserLog['nom']
sonPrenom = dataUserLog['prenom']
userTest = Profil.objects.get(nom=sonNom, prenom=sonPrenom)
idTest = userTest.pk
```

So in variable "idTest" I have now the current user id.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

user_log=Model.objects.get(some_id='some_id')
id =user.id
print(id)
Better you can try this

Comment: But I don't know id. So how can I use it ?

Comment: okay for that case you can try like this user_log=Model.objects.get().first()

Comment: Oh. Please, I don't well explain. In fact I have already logged user and its name and pseudo are in session. So I would like to get current id for current user logged. Thanks for understanding and my apologize for first post